# Failing to Consume Typescript Compiled ESNext customElements in Angular Project Via NPM

Tags: angular, typescript, custom-element

We are having an implementation of HTMLElement's customElements written as a typescript file(`RoleSelector.ts`). This application then generates a private npm package to have compiled `RoleSelector.js` and `RoleSelector.d.ts`. The tsconfig.json has `"target": "ES6", "module": "ESNext",`

```
export class RoleSelector extends HTMLElement {
   // Class Implementation to render shadowElement
    constructor() {
      super();
     // Attach a shadow root to encapsulate the custom element's styles and DOM tree
    this.shadow = this.attachShadow({ mode: 'open' });

    // Initial render
    this.shadow.innerHTML = <HTML-TEMPLATE-HERE>;
}
// Define the custom element
customElements.define('tenant-role-selector', TenantRoleSelector);
```

We are trying to use this npm package in Angular project (V16) . However this gives a runtime error  when project is started

```
Uncaught syntaxerror unexpected token 'export' (at.
```

Do i need to make any changes in my consuming angular application or compile the tsc files differently?

[image]